# Ruby-on-rails gem failing for "where" condition of meta_where

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, meta-where

I have a question about what is probably a gems problem, but may be meta-where.  I used gems to install meta_where-1.0.4, and the response was that I succeeded and the uri for meta_where was provided, but when I tried a where-condition in the search method of a controller, similar to this example that meta-where provides:

```
Person.where(:skill_set.matches => 'Hello%'
```

an error was reported:

```
"undefined method 'matches' for :skill_set:Symbol"
```

It's as if the gem's methods aren't being accessed.  I tried using "require" but that didn't help.
I'm using Windows XP, Firefox, Ruby 1.9.2.

What do I need to do?
Thanks, Barney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have run the migrations and there is a `skill_set` attribute in the `person` table: you don't need `require`. Just add `'gem meta_where'` to your Gemfile and then run `'bundle install'`.

Comment: Thank you!  The problem was that I was using the wrong gemfile, so when you told me what I thought I knew I realized that I didn't understand gemfiles well enough and discovered that I wasn't using the one in the rails project directory.  ".matches" works now!